# Knockout - Using foreach and sort together

Tags: knockout.js, foreach, breeze, ko.observablearray

I am having trouble combining the foreach binding with a sort.  I have a list bound like so:

```
<article data-bind="foreach: widgets">
```

Widgets is a simple obvservable array:

```
var widgets= ko.observableArray();
```

This works nicely giving me a list of my "widgets".  If I add a new "widget" to this list then it appears dynamically in the list via data binding.

However as soon as I add sorting to the array:

```
<article data-bind="foreach: widgets.sort(function (left, right) { return left.order() == right.order() ? 0 : (left.order() < right.order() ? -1 : 1); })">
```

Then newly added widgets no longer appear in my list - unless I reload the page.  (The sorting works nicely at this point - if I update the "order" field that I am sorting on then the items in my list are dynamically re-sorted).

How can I go about getting the sorting to play nicely with the dynamic updating of new items in my observable array?

I am using Breezejs in order to retrieve my data, however I do not think that is impacting on this scenario.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `observableArray.sort` returns the sorted underlying ("regular") array and not a   `observableArray` that is why the changes not shown on the UI.

To have the sorting and the UI updated you need to create a `ko.computed` which does the sorting and use the computed in your binding. Because the `ko.computed` will listen on the `widgets` changes and recalculate the sorting.

```
var widgets= ko.observableArray();

var sortedWidgets = ko.computed(function() {
   return widgets().sort(function (left, right) { 
        return left.order() == right.order() ? 
             0 : 
             (left.order() < right.order() ? -1 : 1); 
   });
});
```

Then you can bind it with:

```
<article data-bind="foreach: sortedWidgets" />
```

Comment: Thank- you - that worked nicely.  Can you please update your answer to include "function () " at the start of the ko.computed (inside the first parentheses).  I will then accept it as the answer.

Comment: Further to your answer above, how do I then make this work for a nested foreach i.e. a foreach on a navigation property of one of the widgets in my top level list.  In this case I do not explicitly declare the observable array that I am binding to so I cannot see how to use this approach.

Comment: I've fixed the typo in my answer. I'm not familiar with Breezejs but I think it can be configured to create these custom sorted properties for you. Anyway JS is dynamic so you can add new properties to any already existing object.

Comment: I was able to get the sorting to work on the nested foreach for the navigation properties by adding a knockout computed property to my Breeze entity in a custom constructor - see http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities.

Comment: @daveywc Could you post an example of how you were able to that while using sort?